# Create flat feeds in batch process

Tags: getstream-io

I want to know if we can create flat **feeds in a batch process.**

Let me give you some context: We want to create feeds for university students based on the courses they are taking. We want them to see feeds for every course that is available at their campus. We have the list of those courses in our MongoDB. Is it possible to create a flat feed for each course on that list in a batch process? There are more than 5000 courses in total.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Also, until you actually put activities into feeds, nothing is being done.

Feed group should be created at your dashboard, for example `course` in this case. Then, actual feed, for example `math-101`, will come to existence when you push data to it.

Nonexisting feed read will simply return empty result set (assuming access policies permit).

- `nonexisting:math-101`: error since feed group is missing
- `nonexisting:nonexisting`: error as previous
- `course:nonexisting`: empty response
- `course:math-101`: your data

Finally, if you're ingesting a lot of data, there is an [import mechanism](https://getstream.io/docs/importing_data_feeds/) to process your data efficiently.